# Custom function trough a range with input

Tags: vim

I am doing a mapping to a function that takes a symbol as input() and would "wrap" all the words of selected lines with such symbol:

```
"Quoter/Wrapper
function Quoter(symbol) 
    exe a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 's/\S\+/' . a:symbol . '&' . a:symbol . '/g'
endfunction

map <Leader>QQ :call <line1>,<line2>Quoter(input('Symbol(Quoter)'))<CR>
```

Which seems to work just fine except it's asking for the input multiple times(seems like it's for the number of lines selected), how can I get to it ask just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down a bit from `:help :function`, you end up on `:help :func-range`, which explains how functions handle range. Paraphrasing…

- Without the `range` argument, the function is called *for every line in the given range*:

  ```
  function! Foo()
      echo a:firstline .. ':' .. a:lastline
  endfunction
  :4,8call Foo()
  4:8
  4:8
  4:8
  4:8
  4:8
  ```
- With `range`, the function is called *only once* and expected to handle the range itself:

  ```
  function! Foo() range
      echo a:firstline .. ':' .. a:lastline
  endfunction
  :4,8call Foo()
  4:8
  ```

Note that the way you call the function is incorrect, too:

```
map <key> :call <line1>,<line2>Foo()<CR>
```

- The range comes before `:call`, not before the function name:

  ```
  map <key> :<line1>,<line2>call Foo()<CR>
  ```
- The appropriate range is automatically added by Vim when you execute an Ex command from visual mode, so there is no need for a range:

  ```
  map <key> :call Foo()<CR>
  ```
- Since your mapping is meant to be a visual mode mapping, you should use the appropriate `:map` command:

  ```
  xmap <key> :call Foo()<CR>
  ```
- Since you don't use another mapping in your mapping, explicitly making it non-recursive would be a good idea:

  ```
  xnoremap <key> :call Foo()<CR>
  ```
- If you only use a recent Vim, why not use `:help <Cmd>`?

  ```
  xnoremap <key> <Cmd>call Foo()<CR>
  ```

Comment: That did it. I was looking at the wrong places. Thank you :)